# Running PEX exposed along garage ceiling for spigot

Tags: plumbing, pex

I was planning on running PEX-A from my basement, through my garage to the exterior cement brick wall (20-30 ft) and down where I'd like to put a small spigot (maybe will a small run of copper along the wall for stability).  Unfortunately my joists run perpendicular to where I want to run the pipe and I have a finished ceiling.

I'm aware of the environmental concerns with PEX - if I run the tube along anchored to the finished ceiling, and not exposed to any direct sunlight (maybe what would get reflected back up from the garage floor) - is this still a concern?

I am in a cold weather environment (NorthEast) but I'm running it from a shutoff valve in the basement.

Comment: Smoothed concrete can reflect a significant portion of UV radiation... You could have problems in as little as a year. Are the garage walls insulated as well, btw? If not then you may have freezing issues to contend with, to boot.

Comment: Yea - the freezing issue is why I wanted to run PEX - then I can shut the water off from inside and drain the line in the winter

Comment: IMHO since the PEX would be exposed, I think it would be worth it to insulate the PEX with pipe insulation or even some cheap [pool noodles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_noodle). Gives a bit of protection from freezing and from UV radiation. But I'm sure you will find nearly as many opinions as the number of people you ask.